# SQL46010 Syntax Error when creating a stored procedure in Visual Studio 15

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2015, syntax-error

First time question on here as there are usually answers already provided but I can't find an appropriate one for my issue.

I have created a database table in Visual Studio 15 and am trying to create a stored procedure to add data.  However, I am getting the SQL46010 error and it is stating 'Incorrect syntax near User'.  My code is below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BugAddOrEdit]
    @mode nvarchar(10),
    @BugID int,
    @User nvarchar(50),
    @Subject nvarchar(50),
    @Description nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    IF @mode = 'Add'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Bugs(User, Subject, Description)
        VALUES (@User, @Subject, @Description)
    END
```

I just can't figure out how to get it to go away. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: try wrapping the word `User` around `[ ]` like this `[User]`

Comment: `User` is a (reserved) **keyword** in SQL Server - try to avoid using it as column or table name. If you **must** use it, then put it in square brackets:`INSERT INTO Bugs([User], Subject, Description) .....` - check the [complete list of reserved keywords for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) and try to avoid those as identifiers in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BugAddOrEdit]
    @mode nvarchar(10),
    @BugID int,
    @User nvarchar(50),
    @Subject nvarchar(50),
    @Description nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    IF @mode = 'Add'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Bugs([User], Subject, Description)
        VALUES (@User, @Subject, @Description)
    END
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That did the trick.  I knew it would be something simple but I just couldn't find the answer anywhere.  Thanks again